# conditional regex for letter followed by number and vice versa

Tags: javascript, regex

- My string can only be 2 character long
- 1st character can be a digit or alphabet
- If 1st is digit, then 2nd should only be alphabet, vice-versa

E.g: `1A`, `A1`, `h2`, `6h` are valid but `11`, `12`, `aa`, `Bb`, `BB` are invalid.

I came up with this regex pattern:

```
\d[a-zA-Z]{1}|[a-zA-Z]\d{1}
```

That works just fine. Any thoughts on how to rewrite it as a conditional regex is appreciated.

Comment: Where does HTML come in here? When you say conditional, do you mean like [`^(?(?=[a-z])[a-z]\d|\d[a-z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/aN9tC3/1)? JS does not support this notation. But you can just use [`^(?:(?=[a-z])[a-z]\d|\d[a-z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/aN9tC3/2). It does not yield any benefit though, `^(?:\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]\d)$` is already good.

Comment: `{1}` is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a negative lookahead `^(?![a-zA-Z]{2}|\d\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{2}$` (though this is longer than your regex)

- don't accept two letters OR two digits `(?![a-zA-Z]{2}|\d\d)`
- looking for two characters: digit and letter OR letter and digit `[a-zA-Z\d]{2}`